# SELECT pg_reload_conf() not working after config changes using ALTER SYSTEM SET (postgresql 14)

Tags: postgresql

In the past, when I've made some config changes (e.g. to increase `max_connections`) I have been able to make those changes take effect without restarting the db server by using `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`... [as per the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html).

But now, it isn't working... I've recently upgraded to postgresql 14 so maybe that's it?  Any ideas?  The config change is making it's way into the `postgresql.auto.conf` file, and it does take effect after restarting the server, but I'd like to know why `pg_reload_conf()` isn't working.

Example flow below:

```
# SHOW max_connections;
 max_connections 
-----------------
 300
(1 row)

# ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = '301';
ALTER SYSTEM

# SHOW max_connections;
 max_connections 
-----------------
 300
(1 row)

# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
(1 row)

# SHOW max_connections;
 max_connections 
-----------------
 300
(1 row)


# more /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.auto.conf
# Do not edit this file manually!
# It will be overwritten by the ALTER SYSTEM command.
shared_buffers = '2GB'
wal_buffers = '64MB'
work_mem = '8MB'
maintenance_work_mem = '128MB'
max_connections = '301'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS)

> Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during initdb). **This parameter can only be set at server start.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So this is expected, `max_connections` can't be changed without a restart of the server.

Comment: That's it, thanks!